# Crontab/Perl piping magic

Tags: linux, bash, cron, io-redirection, redirectstandardoutput

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the bash shell, what is “ 2>&1 ”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21)

I recently saw this in a crontab:

```
5 * * * * perl /abs/path/to/my/script.pl >> /abs/path/two/my/script-log.txt 2>&1
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it runs `script.pl` every hour, 5 minutes after the hour (so 2:05, 3:05, 10:05, etc.). Again, if I'm correct, it is redirecting standard output to a log file located elsewhere.

But what is this Linux/Perl voo-doo at the end of the crontab?

> 2>&1

What is this instructing Linux/Perl to do? And if my above interpretation of the crontab is incorrect, please clarify for me as well! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect file descriptor 2 (stderr) over 1; it's the idiomatic way to tell /bin/sh that stderr should go in the same place as stdout

Answer (score 0):

It's bourne shell syntax to associate file descriptor 2 (STDERR) with file descriptor 1 (STDOUT), in effect sending STDERR to `/abs/path/two/my/script-log.txt`.